# Skype connections breaks often

Tags: skype

For some weeks, I still have the problem of breaking a Skype call. So sometimes up to 5 times per hour, the calls to different partners ends without any reason.

We can immediately redial with success. Sometimes a parallel running download is continuing without breaking.

Is that a known issue? I have no ideas on how I can improve the situation.

Comment: We surely need more information for this: OS, Wi-Fi or Ethernet, Skype for Windows 10 or Skype Client, have you noticed any connection issues, etc..

Comment: I use the Skype App for Windows 10 (x64) Version 14.54.91.0. I have no information about used systems on other sides. My computer is connected via LAN. There are no connection problems. Parallel running download continuing without interruption.